# Django perform CRUD on multiple models

Tags: python, django, backend, crud

Is it possible to perform CRUD operations on multiple Django models without creating an html template and writing a View function for each and every operation. For example, say you have the following model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

With this one model, to perform CRUD operations, you would define a function for each operation in `views.py` (4 functions) and create a template for each, i.e., `create_employee.html`, `retrieve_employee.html`, `update_employee.html`, `delete_employee.html`.

Now, say instead of just an `Employee` model, there's 20 models that you want to be able to perform CRUD operations on. Do you have to create CRUD functions for each model in `views.py` and also create a template for each operation for each model? Or is there a simpler way? For example, create one function per model in `views.py` that performs the CRUD operations and one template per model?

Answer (score 0):

You can make one view for three operations: CREATE, READ and UPDATE. A ModelForm can make automatically difference between creation and updating. for Reading, it is just a displaying of data store in the modelform with an instance. You do not speak about LIST operation, which need another view...
Not really need to make form in some cases. you can just define `fields` attribute in the generic view too

Afterwards, what you are asking for is the django admin interface instead.
Because the advantage of developing each view and form independently is to be able to adjust the behavior of each action whose logic will not be automatically definable in the model over the long term. If there is no logic besides simple CRUD: might as well use the Django admin I think.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I wanted to avoid ModelForm because I want to be able to customize the pages using HTML and CSS. You lose flexibility with ModelForm if I understand correctly, right? Also, the purpose of this project is for there to be multiple non-admin who can perform CRUD operations on the data.